# design issue from windows phone emulator to real windows phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am a absolute beginner to develop windows phone application. Using VS 2013 and targeting windows phone 8.1 device.

I have developed an application where the design is good in windows phone emulator. But when I install the same in real device it's design has gone and everything got messed up.

Anyhow I have figured out that I am using pixel values everywhere - it could be the issue.

How can I give percentage values instead of pixel - I am bit confused here.

Is anything else like this I have to keep it mind in terms of design from Windows phone emulator to real windows phone.

Any Suggestion/Ideas/Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ilaiya.

Answer (score 0):

Your device probably has different resolution than default emulator which has WVGA (480x800). Windows Phone SDK provides emulators with all supported resolutions. You can check your app on emulator with 720p resolution which has different aspect ratio from WVGA.

> Anyhow I have figured out that I am using pixel values everywhere - it could be the issue.
>
> How can I give percentage values instead of pixel - I am bit confused here.

You cannot give percentage values in XAML. Pixel values corresponds to WVGA resolution and on phones with bigger resolution are scaled up with appropriate scale factors.

More information about scaling and supporting multiple resolutions can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[@smockersmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29550074/4184842)'s answer is *mostly* correct for Silverlight-based apps, but based on your description that the design is "messed up" I suspect you are building a Universal app. (There are only minor differences in height for Silverlight-based apps, but major differences in height and width for Universal apps).

I suggest you [read this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx) and possibly [watch my //build talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-541) about scaling in new Universal apps, and if you want to do side-by-side comparisons on different emulators, try [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2014/04/03/optimum-emulator-sizes-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx) for an optimum setup.

Comment: Thanks peter. You links are useful.